# Android - ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, actionbardrawertoggle

Hi I am getting this error in the 
ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved when I import this in my activity **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;**
I have already imported appcompact_v7 and android-support-v7-appcompact libaries.

It gives no error when I import 
**import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;**

I need ActionBarDrawerToggle for implementing the Action Bar.
I have tried everything.

P.S: I am using Eclipse

Comment: with 22.1.1 you should use AppCompatActivity instead of AcionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile the v7 support library with your project. 
Here's an example `build.gradle` for AndroidStudio:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Hi , I am using eclipse. Can you suggest something for that ?

Comment: @RahulArora [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) can.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, you need import `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat` to your project as a library. Refer to this doc [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: I have used the same constructor as you suggested. The error is only in imports.